# Force helper 'action' to use HTTPS

Tags: laravel

{{ action('controller@post') }} is not returning the https. Forms are unable to submit because of this.

Moved to a new server and now having issues with https not be recognized.

`{{ action('controller@post') }}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `action` helper uses the `UrlGenerator` underneath.
There are multiple solutions to this problem.

1.

You can force Laravel to always use `https` by running

```
URL::forceScheme('https');
```

In your `AppServiceProvider`.

2.

Set your `APP_URL` in your `.env` to have `https://` at the front. eg.

```
APP_ULR=https://example.org
```

3.
Add `scheme => 'https'` to your group config in you route.

```
Route::group([scheme => 'https']), function(Router $route) {
    $route->get('secured_route')
}
```

4.

Use the `secure_url()` helper. It will always generate a `https` url.

Comment: Good to know. I just updated my answer with a bunch of other ways to do it. 
If you do not always need `https`, for example when developing locally, then I'll recommend using the `APP_URL` method, as it depends on your env settings.